# backbone layout manager: how to remove child views

Tags: backbone.js

How to clean up the children view when the parent view is removed. There are some cleanup activities involved in the child view. when I call the remove parent view there is no hook to remove the child view.

Answer (score 0):

add the close function to your parent view (**it:** *it was good if all children extends parent view or all your views extends a gad view, and the close function is inside the gad view* )

```
close: function() {
  var err, i, view, _ref1;

  try {
    _ref1 = this.childViews;
    for (i in _ref1) {
      view = _ref1[i];
      if (typeof view.close === "function") {
        view.close();
      }
    }
    this.unbind();
    this.stopListening();
    this.undelegateEvents();
    return this.$el.empty();
  } catch (_error) {
    err = _error;
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I could not explain my mind, I want to say that all children views must have the close function.